# Automapper: how to ignore a navigation property in EF (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, automapper

I'm new to EF and to AutoMapper, and I'm trying to use it to create a web service. If I try to serialize EF entities directly, the navigation properties throw errors because they can't be serialized. I'd like to find a way to suppress them, and I'm told the best way to do this is to create POCOs to use as Data Transfer Objects.

(At this point I'm thinking I might as well write my own DTOs using ADO.NET - isn't EF supposed to save me the trouble of writing my own classes?)

I've had AutoMapper recommended to me as a way to automatically map EF entities to POCOs, so I tried using it in the following procedure, which loads the POCO:

```
Public Sub Load(ByVal lngUserId As Long)

    Dim query = From u In db.Users
                Where u.UserID = lngUserId
                Select u

    AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(query.FirstOrDefault(), Me)

End Sub
```

Problem is, it comes up with an error that turns out to be related to the navigation property again, which it appears is not automatically ignored by AutoMapper.

So, I've tried adding this line to force AutoMapper to ignore the nav property:

```
Dim oMap = Mapper.CreateMap(Of User, UserDto).ForSourceMember(Sub(src) src.tblUserFarms, Sub(opt) opt.Ignore())
```

(tblUserFarms is the nav property)

I converted the syntax for this from a C# example I found, but it appears that the first parameter of .ForSourceMember isn't supposed to be a Lambda expression, and I can't find a good example of how it should be used.

Am I using the right approach, or should I be trying something else altogether? Should I simply delete all my nav properties in order to work around the problem, and lose their benefits? Is EF even the right tool for the job?

Comment: At this point I've had to move on with my project, so I've opted to write my own mapping code, putting some to/from mapping methods into my DTOs, converting the nav properties from ICollections to Lists where needed. Not the most elegant solution, but it gives me full control. And yes, I've come to the conclusion that EF doesn't actually save me any coding time at all, I still have to write just as much plumbing code - the only difference is I'm writing LINQ queries instead of SQL, and have the option to change RDBMS later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a code snippet of how I have been doing it. With the ignores in place I avoid getting the navigation property objects from being loaded (improve performance as well).

```
public domain.Entities.UserProfile GetUserProfile(string userName)
    {

        Mapper.CreateMap<Entities.UserProfile, domain.Entities.UserProfile>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.BillingAddress, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ShippingAddress, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Orders, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ShoppingCartItems, opt => opt.Ignore());

        Entities.UserProfile storedProfile = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName.Equals(userName));
        var profile = Mapper.Map<Entities.UserProfile, domain.Entities.UserProfile>(storedProfile);

        return profile;
    }
```

This is how I have defined my UserProfile

```
 public class UserProfile
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Prefix { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual string Company { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string FaxNumber { get; set; }

    private ICollection<ShoppingCartItem> _shoppingCartItems;
    private ICollection<Address> _addresses;
    private ICollection<Order> _orders;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default billing address
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default shipping address
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets customer addresses
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses
    {
        get { return _addresses ?? (_addresses = new List<Address>()); }
        protected set { _addresses = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets orders
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders
    {
        get { return _orders ?? (_orders = new List<Order>()); }
        protected set { _orders = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets shopping cart items
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems
    {
        get { return _shoppingCartItems ?? (_shoppingCartItems = new List<ShoppingCartItem>()); }
        protected set { _shoppingCartItems = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Geovani, I'll definitely give that a go some time. Unfortunately my project is too far along to change back to Automapper from the custom code I'm using now though.